# Unable to access the website when Anonymous access is unchecked

Tags: c#, .net, iis, web-config

I have simple webapp , which need to get the current logged on user name of the system.

I tried with :

```
  Label1.Text = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

But this was blank as Anonymous User access was checked. When I unchecked Anonymous user Access then I am unable to browse the web site with error

> You are not authorized to view this page

I am using windows authentication in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

Comment: What about `Integrated Windows authentication` checkbox?

Comment: Integrated Windows authentication checkbox is checked

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Windows auth, and disable the Anonymous access, you must provide the Windows user information to your webapp.

Use `<identity impersonate="true"/>` for this.

Comment: @sehe It is false by default. And @Subhen use the windows auth, so we need to push info about user to the web site.

Comment: @sehe This is not about access to the files. This is about the way to auth user.

Comment: Whatever; I was assuming from the (incomplete) information that the OP knows Windows Integrated Auth; I'm just trying to help, not correct you

Comment: This page is displayed because of anonimous user is disabled, and impersonation (with getting the user from windows) is off. First thing to check - is user impersonated or not.

Comment: @VMAtm, after making impersonation true still I am not able to access it. Updated the question for details

Comment: @Subhen:  What browser are you using?  Only IE supports this.  It also requires your work station to be part of the same domain as the server.